# Validate only if a radio has a specific value checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck with validation combined with a jQuery condition. Can somebody please give me a good hint? Help is appreciated :)

This is my code, the validation works fine without condition, but it should only work if one of the values of the radio "shipping_method" is selected.

```
var shipping = jQuery('input[name="shipping_method"]:checked').val();
    if(shipping == 'matrixrate_matrixrate_2048') {
        Validation.add('validate-alphanumeric', 'Please enter number.', function(v) {   
        return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /[0-9]+/m.test(v);
    });
};
```

Maybe this is the wrong way, all I want is to check if a number is added to an address if condition is true.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please add you markup aswell

Comment: Did you try comparison, as in `if(shipping === 'matrixrate_matrixrate_2048') {` instead of assigment

Comment: Markup? You mean <script></script>? So I am not a programmer.

Comment: Adeneo, 3x === is not working.

Comment: @HenkProvily it may help to provide the resulting HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using just one `=` in you if condition, when you do this you will change the variable value and the return will be the new value that variable, in this case the return will be 'matrixrate_matrixrate_2048' and this will enter in your if condition. For to compare you need use `==` or `===`. That will work.

```
var shipping = jQuery('input[name="shipping_method"]:checked').val();
    if(shipping === 'matrixrate_matrixrate_2048') { /* <---- Here the change */
        Validation.add('validate-alphanumeric', 'Please enter number.', function(v) {   
        return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /[0-9]+/m.test(v);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering.
I solved it by using the addClass and removeClass in the condition and put the validation seperate. So now it will only validate if the class is added and that works.